# Basic Series Question-Euler

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm studying Calc 2 and I have a basic series question.

Leonhard Euler discovered that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$.

Given $\sum \:_{n=1}^{\infty \:}\:\frac{1}{\left(2n\right)^2}$, what does the series equal?

My work:

Let k=2n
$\sum \:_{k=2}^{\infty \:}\:\frac{1}{k^2}=\sum \:_{n=1}^{\infty \:}\:\frac{1}{\left(2n\right)^2}$.

Now $\sum \:_{k=2}^{\infty \:}\:\frac{1}{k^2}=-1+\sum \:_{k=1}^{\infty \:}\:\frac{1}{\left(k\right)^2}$

Finally: $\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-1=-1+\sum \:\:_{k=1}^{\infty \:\:}\:\frac{1}{\left(k\right)^2}$

My textbook says that $\sum \:_{n=1}^{\infty \:}\:\frac{1}{\left(2n\right)^2}$=$\frac{\pi ^2}{24}$ though I cannot see how, based on my work above.

Does anyone see an error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your sum should run over the evens $[2,4,6,\cdots]$, not just start from 2, $[2,3,4\cdots]$

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter already pointed out - your $k$ sum is over even numbers. It excludes more than just the first term.

If you'd like a hint, see if you can use this: $(2n)^{2}=4n^{2}$.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I see the solution now. What I'm confused about is why my k substitution didn't work. I usually use that form of substitution when I want to change the index, with no problem.

Comment: In the past, you have probably used the change of index for expressions like $n+1$, which is just a shift and much easier to correct. With $2n$, you skip an infinite number of indices.

Comment: @findingmyway If I have answered your question, I would really appreciate you accepting my answer. I'm trying to get full site privileges.

Answer (score 0):

In summations, one should avoid scaling of the summation index like $2k=p$.
Because then then you have to cosider the even terms in the summand.
The correct way would be to write $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(2k)^2}$$, then use $2k=p$, to write $$S=\sum_{p=2}^{\infty~~'}\frac{1}{p^2}$$ notice prime over sigma, this will remind you that you cannot take $p=2,3,4,5,6,...$ instead you have to take $p=2,4,6,8...$
Then, $$S=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{1}{8^2}+...$$
$$\implies S=\frac{1}{2^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+....\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{24}$$

However, it is better to avoid transformation which scales the summing index like $p=2k, p=2k+1, p=3k+1, p=3k+4..$ transformations which shift the summation index are OK like $p=n+2, p=n-2, p=n+4, p=n+7,....$

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!